# Put site to offline mode from front-end

Tags: global-configuration

I have a need for my Admin users to set the site to Offline mode without going to Joomla back-end. I thought of doing this with a PHP-script, but I cannot figure out how to update values in configuration.php with a php.

Thanks in advance!